# The set of all points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ that must belong to an infinite number of sets.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Let $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Why does the set

$$A:=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty} E_n\right),$$

consist of the points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ that are in infinitely many of the $E_k$'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ belongs to only finitely many of those sets. Then, there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that is the largest for which $x \in E_k$. Then, for all $n \geq k+1, x \notin E_n$, so $x \notin \cup_{n=k+1}^\infty E_n$.

Conversely, if $x \in E_n$ for infinitely many $n$, then for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a $k' > k$ for which $x \in E_{k'}$. Therefore, $x \in \cup_{n  = k}^\infty E_n$ for all $k$, so $x$ is in the intersection of all such sets.